# Consulta en responsive design con css grid

Tags: css, css3

estoy practicando responsive design con grid, al momento de usar una media query pensado para dispositivos mas pequeños, el diseño queda pensado para tener una columna y cuatro filas pero se forma un espacio entre las primeras 2 filas y las ultimas 2 filas, en este link se puede visualizar el problema https://codepen.io/tommy-solano-pe-afiel/pen/MNopGe?editors=1100

```css
    .container {
    
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 15% 60% 20%;
        grid-template-rows: 15% 85%;
        grid-gap: 20px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        grid-template-areas: "item1 item1 item1"
                             "item2 item3 item4"
    }
    
    .item1 {
    
        grid-column: 1 / 4;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 50%;
        grid-area: item1;
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }
    
    .item2 {
    
        background-color: rgb(97, 209, 97);
        grid-area: item2;
    }
    
    .item3 {
    
        background-color: yellow;
        grid-area: item3;
    }
    
    .item4 {
    
        background-color: gray;
        grid-area: item4;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    
        .container {
            grid-template-areas: "item1 item1 item1"
                                 "item2 item3 item3"
                                 "item2 item4 item4";                       
        }
        .container > div {
    
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    
        .container {
            grid-template-areas: "item1 item1 item1"
                                 "item2 item2 item2"
                                 "item3 item3 item3"
                                 "item4 item4 item4";
        }
        .container {
            grid-gap: 0px;
            align-content: start;
        }
        .container .item1 {
            max-height: 200px;
        }
        .container .item2 {
            max-height: 200px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: cuando pasas a resoluciones pequeñas tienes una sola columna y cuatro filas pero no cambias la propiedad `grid-template-rows` y la segunda fila ocupa el 85% pero su contenido es menor y sobra mucho espacio

Comment: @blonfu estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario. Que tal si lo agregas como respuesta! Digo, por aquello de que sirva para referencia de futuros visitantes... _bueno, y también por aquello de la reputación_